# Translating or Interpreting JavaScript from PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Any tips on running JavaScript code from PHP?  I'm trying to run a javascript function and get its return value.  This is a LOT easier in this case than translating it myself into PHP. Would [Spidermonkey](http://pecl.php.net/package/spidermonkey) be good for this task, or something else?

UPDATE: On the other hand, if there's an app for translating the JavaSCcript into PHP once instead of just interpreting it, that might be better.  So I'd be interested in recommendations on that front..

Thanks much

Comment: what does the script do?

Comment: Does some crc32 stuff, some math, then outputs a unique user ID based on all that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

[J4P5](http://j4p5.sourceforge.net/) (quite basic) or [V8JS](http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php) (I haven't tried it)

I guess Spidermonkey can do the job as well... I have used J4P5 just very few so I can't suggest too much.

Comment: How much slower would V8JS be than translating the code into php?

Comment: How complex is your code? I think that if your code is not going to change that much (as you said, is to generate an ID), then I would definitely translate it into PHP. If that code will change often and it is better for you to do it in JS, then use a JS engine as V8JS, etc. All depends on how much different you PHP code will be from the one you have in JS. I haven't test the performance of J4P5 as I used it to run some tests but I guess that if you want performance, then that is not the best to do.

Comment: Other way you may consider is to translate your code to C/C++, compile it and then run it from PHP. If it performs very complex math, then you may gain performance in the math but you will loose some performance on the execution from PHP. It could also add extra security (as reading the PHP code will not show how the ID was calculated). If security is not your concern, then why that ID is so unique? perhaps looking for other ways to generate a unique ID in PHP could be faster, don't you think?

Comment: I don't know of any automatic JS -> PHP converter (and I guess there is not such a thing). Maybe your code can be divided in parts, and maybe some of those parts are already implemented in PHP (so you don't have to do the work). Only the parts that are missing you may need to rewrite them in PHP. You can ask for help in this community (you know). I'm sure someone could help you.